# How to palm-mute bass notes only?

Tags: guitar, palm-muting

I heard about a fingerstyle technique where you palm mute the bass line but not the melody line.

I've been trying to figure it out but have a couple of issues. I try to lay my palm so that it touches only the E A D strings, but this hand position makes it very difficult to play all the strings. Also, I'm having trouble muting all three strings equally, with E being more muted than D.

How does this technique work? I didn't manage to find anything with Google.

Comment: Not an answer, but a simple solution. Cut a piece of sponge, to go under the bottom three strings, close to the bridge. You'll have to experiment a bit, to find how much muting *you* need.

Comment: Wow, never even considered changing the instrument. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious answer is practice (as it usually is) but you can use various techniques to make things easier.

One useful trick to limiting muting to just the bass strings is to mute right at the bridge, and rest the side of your palm on the bridge itself. You can then place your hand in a way that moves the contact position on the top three strings behind the bridge while keeping the contact position for the bass strings in front of the bridge.

What this gives you is a relatively fixed position so you don't accidentally start to mute higher strings or release the damping on lower strings.